# how to upload your local repo to a designated remote repo in Github when you have two Github accounts and one of them is set as default?

Tags: github

First of all, I tried to edit SSH/config file by adding a newly generated key, its hostname and so forth. Didn't work. Every time I tried to upload a repo to my personal github account, git would try to upload it to my work github account. My question is really, should I modify SSH/config or .git/config, are those two different? For the record, these are the sources of inspiration I am refering to here. (1)http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-mac.html
(2)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnSRBRiQIU8
neither of them works. In addition, as I opened the SSH/config file, there is no trace of the SSH keys which is connected to my work github account, which I've been using for a while. I literally started using github actively two and a half months ago, and a colleague helped me set up everything. I am using a mac. Where is my work SSH keys stored?
Thank you very much! All of your advice would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: This might help you. [about remote repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories). [managing remote repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories).

Comment: What do you see for the url for [remote "origin"] in `.git/config`?

Does it start with git@github or `https://github.com`?